repeated errors with rstatix::anova_test function
I have a data frame named "weeks" with the following structure:
 head(weeks,n=5)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  group bag_number   H50
  <fct> <chr>      <dbl>
1 2     bag_5       4.57
2 2     bag_6       4.62
3 2     bag_7       4.56
4 2     bag_8       4.65
5 2     bag_9       4.47


When I try to use the function statix::anova_test
omnibus<-rstatix::anova_test(data = weeks, dv = H50, wid=bag_number, within = group)

I get an error:
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks
